# My contract compiles, but when deploying I get an error

Tags: smart-contracts, contract

I'm using the Teztool in sandbox mode. [My contract](https://github.com/roppa/tezart/blob/master/contract/tezart.ligo) compiles, but when I deploy:

```
teztool carthagenet sandbox client originate contract tezart transferring 0 from bootstrap1 running tezart.tz
```

I get this:

```
Warning:

   The node you are connecting to claims to be running in a
                    Tezos TEST SANDBOX.
      Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.
  You should not see this message if you are not a developer.

Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
This simulation failed:
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0
    Expected counter: 1
    Gas limit: 800000
    Storage limit: 60000 bytes
    Origination:
      From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
      Credit: ꜩ0
      Script:
        { parameter
            (or (or (pair %createArtwork (string %0) (string %1))
                    (pair %transfer (string %0) (address %1)))
                (string %updateArtist)) ;
          storage
            (pair (map %artists address string)
                  (map %artwork
                     string
                     (pair (pair (address %artist) (string %ipfsArtworkAddress)) (address %owner)))) ;
          code { DUP ;
                 CDR ;
                 PUSH mutez 0 ;
                 AMOUNT ;
                 COMPARE ;
                 NEQ ;
                 IF { PUSH string "This is a tokenless contract" ; FAILWITH }
                    { PUSH unit Unit } ;
                 DIP 2 { DUP } ;
                 DIG 2 ;
                 CAR ;
                 IF_LEFT
                   { DUP ;
                     IF_LEFT
                       { DUP ;
                         DIP 4 { DUP } ;
                         DIG 4 ;
                         DIP { DUP ; CAR } ;
                         PAIR ;
                         DIP { DUP ; CDR } ;
                         PAIR ;
                         DUP ;
                         CAR ;
                         CAR ;
                         DUP ;
                         DIP 2 { DUP } ;
                         DIG 2 ;
                         CAR ;
                         CDR ;
                         DIP { DIP 2 { DUP } ;
                               DIG 2 ;
                               CDR ;
                               SENDER ;
                               PAIR ;
                               SENDER ;
                               SWAP ;
                               PAIR ;
                               SOME ;
                               DIP { DIP { DUP } ; SWAP ; CDR } } ;
                         UPDATE ;
                         SWAP ;
                         CAR ;
                         PAIR ;
                         DIP { DROP 4 } }
                       { DIP 3 { DUP } ; DIG 3 ; DIP { DROP } } ;
                     DIP { DROP } }
                   { DIP 2 { DUP } ;
                     DIG 2 ;
                     DIP { DUP } ;
                     PAIR ;
                     DUP ;
                     CAR ;
                     DUP ;
                     DIP 2 { DUP } ;
                     DIG 2 ;
                     CDR ;
                     SOME ;
                     DIP { DIP { DUP } ; SWAP ; CAR } ;
                     SENDER ;
                     UPDATE ;
                     SWAP ;
                     CDR ;
                     SWAP ;
                     PAIR ;
                     DIP { DROP 3 } } ;
                 NIL operation ;
                 PAIR ;
                 DIP { DROP 3 } } }
        Initial storage: Unit
        No delegate for this contract
        This operation FAILED.

Ill typed data: 1: Unit
is not an expression of type
  pair (map %artists address string)
       (map %artwork
          string
          (pair (pair (address %artist) (string %ipfsArtworkAddress)) (address %owner)))
At line 1 characters 0 to 4, value Unit
is invalid for type
  pair (map %artists address string)
       (map %artwork
          string
          (pair (pair (address %artist) (string %ipfsArtworkAddress)) (address %owner))).
At line 1 characters 0 to 4,
invalid primitive Unit, only Pair can be used here.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide an initial storage value for your contract. You can write it in Ligo and compile it too using the `ligo compile-storage` command.

Comment: Yes! Got it working with `ligo compile-storage tezart.ligo main "record [ artists = ((map[]) : artists);  artwork = ((map[]) : artworks)]"`